# Can Windows 7 place a task bar on each monitor, which only shows applications running on that screen?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I would like to have a task bar on each of my monitors, but I only want applications that are currently on that monitor to be displayed on its taskbar.

This can be accomplished using [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/). However, the taskbar shown on the secondary and tertiary monitors is not the native Windows 7 taskbar, but rather made to try to simulate how it looks and feels. As good as it is, it is missing a ton of the features I find to be the best about the taskbar, such as program grouping, "peeking" at applications and so forth.

Is there is a way to make Windows 7 actually display its native awesome taskbar on multiple monitors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. Not the native toolbar at least. Sorry mate, you are out of luck here. There's [MonMan](http://code.google.com/p/monman/) for Windows XP - send an email to the dev to see if you can encourage him to make it 7 compatible.

Comment: this is actually VERY cool! and 'portable'... nice find. +1 (although not compatible with Windows 7 and thus not really an answer :)

Comment: @Molly :) One more reason to stick with XP! Gawd I simply can't find a really good reason to get rid of XP besides all the eye-candy and windows-management features of 7.

Comment: only using 7 just so i know 'what's new' ... as a working environment? thanks, but no thanks :) playing with MonMan as we speak, funny: it minimizes Total Commander to the (secondary) taskbar whereas TC goes into the tray when on the primary display. to restore TC from the Monman taskbar, it requires 2 clicks.

Comment: caliban: Your statement makes no sense as this is not possible in XP either. Furthermore, the whole point of my question is I like the extended functionality of the Windows 7 taskbar, which you will of course not get in XP. :)

Comment: on another note, i find it disgrace that Microsoft keeps ignoring multi-monitor setups as if they were some exotic occurrence. proper multi-monitor support should have been a native feature in their latest OS.

Comment: @Molly: While it is a rising trend, especially among corporate circles, to have two or more monitors, majority of users are still single monitor lifeforms. :) The urgency is not there - even Mac OS X has terrible multi-monitor support (Dock, menubar on one monitor only).

Comment: In between getting security + performance right, and adding multimon support, I'd rather MS just devote resources to the first option.

Comment: This is one of those places where a third party can do the work.  I don't care to know the processes on each monitor (becasue most of my processes are in the background as services)

Answer (score 5):

For Windows 7 I'm using **[DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/)**. I find it better than UltraMon.

It shows the thumbnail preview, but minimize to taskbar goes to the native taskbar on the primary display :(

Comment: Thanks for this. Sadly the only thing it seems to have over Ultramon is thumbnail display. Grouping is what I'd really like. :( +1

Comment: Only paid version allows taksbars on multi monitors :(

Answer (score 4):

Multiple screens isn't supported by the taskbar's API (as far as I know), but there's an alternative to UltraMon: [MultiMonitor Taskbar](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm)

Note that it's freeware, though the Pro version actually has some cool features. It supports Windows 2000, XP, Vista, and 7.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Features:

- It adds second taskbar to the extended desktop on Monitor 2
- It can add third taskbar to the second Extended monitor if you have 3 monitors setup.
- It shows only applications from that Monitor
- It hides the applications on Monitor 2 and 3 from normal Windows Taskbar
- Adds a Move to Monitor button to windows applications (XP).
- Add Text Clipboard Extender
- Buttons to roll-right the taskbar (good for full screen Remote Desktop)
- Very carefully written, I don't want to crash my own desktop!

Comment: yep, this one not  bad. pro: i like the clicpboard manager, con: no theme support (in the free version).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. Even if it doesn't do what I want I always like to know of interesting (especially if free!) alternatives to popular software. :)

Comment: Can it add a taskbar to more than 2 monitors?

Answer (score 0):

Another FREE option is [ZBar](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/zbar/index.html) utility. Extremely simple, few options, very basic appearance  customizing - so it looks a bit ugly on W7 (no Aero). But it works and is for free!

[image]

Tested on W7 3-monitor setup.

Answer (score 0):

[Dual Monitor Taskbar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/) is open source and works neat.

I found it while searching and passing by [there](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-extend-task-bar-across-multiple-monitors-in-windows-7).